# Как правильно писать: свыкся или свыкнулся?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, спряжение

1. Сергей ***свыкся*** со скверным характером деда.
2. Сергей ***свыкнулся*** со скверным характером деда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно: ***свыкся***.

См. словари, например: [Викисловарь](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F).

[**СВЫ́КНУТЬСЯ**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1019018), свыкнусь, свыкнешься, прош. вр. свыкся, свыклась...

В Нацкорпусе есть [два примера](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F) с глаголом ***свыкнулся***, но они относятся к XIX веку.